# Inputting text file in python as an argument

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I am new to python. I am writing a code to make changes remotely to cisco switches and my code is as follows:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_sw = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip':   '10.18.120.3',
    'username': 'cisco',
    'password': 'cisco',
    'port' : 22,          # optional, defaults to 22
    'secret': '',     # optional, defaults to ''
    'verbose': False,       # optional, defaults to False
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_sw)
net_connect.find_prompt() # to verify if connection is established
config_commands = [ 'commands']
output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
print(output)
net_connect.exit_config_mode()
output = net_connect.send_command_expect('write memory')
print(output)
output = net_connect.disconnect()
```

I wanted to modify the code so that "ip" in cisco_sw dictionary and "commands" inputted in config_commands can be directly inputted from text file. Please help me to know how to input one line at a time from text file during every iteration.

Comment: Take a look at the standard [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/configparser.html) module.

Comment: Take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module.